# ajax call in mvc using web api

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have written simple webapi method. I am trying to access that method in mvc using ajax call. I am getting output in browser and fiddler . But Its not working in cshtml page.Please let me know , If I have to add something.
Please look into this..

```html
 function validate() {
            alert("came");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:54544/api/home/getname/',
                method: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/form-url-encoded',
                
                success: function ()
                {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert(ex.responseText);
                }
            });

        }
```

[image: Please check this images]

check the html code here

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>View</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestBody('Authorization','Bearer ' + token); } ,

        $(document).ready(function () {

            alert("came");

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:54544/api/home/getname/",
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {

                    alert("test came");

                },
                error: function (msg) { alert("error"); alert(msg); }
            });
        });

    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validate()" name="Submit" /> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>


        </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[how to add request body parameters in ajax request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrbqZ.png)

Comment: I tried removing content type., but Its not working.

Comment: Any error on your browser console? Post your complete `cshtml` and `Layout` page, did you wrap it in section? Because by the default template, if you call `<script></script>` immediately in your `cshtml` without wrapping it in section, it will be called before the `jquery.js` and will cause error because the `jquery.js` is being called after `RenderBody()` in the `Layout` page

Comment: added cshtml. Please check once
and error in console :
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54544/api/home/getname/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:57842' is therefore not allowed access.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are violating the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restriction by trying to make an AJAX call to another domain. For this to work you might need to enable [`CORS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in your Web API. If you are using ASP.NET Web API you may checkout the [`following tutorial`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) which illustrates how this can be done.

Basically you can install the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` NuGet:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

and enable CORS in your bootstrapper:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally decorate your API controller with the `[EnableCors]` attribute:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://www.example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class ItemsController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() { ... }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i got this. and one more doubt, I have attached one image [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WrbqZ.png)
Please let me know how to add req body parameters in ajax call

Comment: You seem to have passed a wrong content type header in your request: `application/form-url-encoded`. The correct content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so make sure that you respect the standard encoding headers when making your HTTP request in Fiddler.